# How to center an image inside an UIButton without stretching in both direction in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am making a custom keyboard and I need to centre the image of the shift icon inside the shift button. The image is 100px x 100px.

However, the button frame in portrait is `36pt x 38pt`, and in landscape, it is `68pt x 32pt`. I have tried using button image inset property to centre the image. However, it does not does so.

I tried myself and set the image edge insets to `(25,25,25,25)`, the image centres in both sizes. However, the icon becomes too small to see.

```
shiftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "shift"), forState: .Normal)

shiftButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
```

I am making the button programatically. And, I need the button to scale maintaining its aspect ratio i.e. `1:1`. Its maximum width or height is always tied to the button's height itself. The image width/height should be maximum of button's height. And, it should not stretch in any way to distort the icon. However, the button itself can stretch.

I need the image to scale according to button frame but maintain its aspect ratio. And, it can down scale or up scale, but should always maintain the 1:1 aspect ratio.

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally a solution came through. You must set the content mode for the image inside the UIButton.

The solution is to update the `contentMode` of the `Image` when you are using a foreground image inside a button along with the `contentMode` of the `UIButton`.

```
shiftButton.contentMode = .Center
shiftButton.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: .center and .scaleAspectFit for latest swift (now using lowerCameCase)

Comment: Where do you place these updates? Somewhere in the sidebar?

Answer (score 17):

If you're using storyboard, double-check that you don't have anything set for the button title.

Comment: This was it buddy, 10x!

Comment: You are still a lifesaver.

Answer (score 14):

- Add User Defined Runtime Attributes to your button.

In the screen shot below value 1 is equal to scaleAspectFit

```
imageView.ContentMode = scaleAspectFit
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was able to center the image by setting the content insets to 0 using the size inspector on the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: This actually worked for me though I changed the image insets to get my image center within the button. I had to set  "left" to 11. I haven't properly sent constraints though, and maybe that's why the above answers didn't work and this one did. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Set the button's content mode to `Center`:

```
shiftButton.contentMode = .Center
```

Comment: I've already tried it. This does not seem to work in this particular case. Maybe, its because the image is larger that the size of frame.

Comment: When the button width starts to stretch, the image seems to stretch as well. And, this behaviour is not desired at all.

Comment: According to the docs `.Center` shouldn't stretch at all: "The option to center the content in the view’s bounds, keeping the proportions the same."

Comment: as of iOS 11 this will only work if you have height and width constraints on the Button.

Answer (score 3):

To work on UIButton with image is sort of tricky things. I think below two lines could solve your problem.

And there is a good post [Aligning text and image on UIButton](https://iostutorialjunction.com/2020/02/swift-tutorials-aligning-text-and-image-on-uibutton-with-help-of-uiedgeinsets.html)

```
// Keep button's image to its original ratio.
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
// Give button image a little space from all the four edges.
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3)
```

##### A button in my project

```
    lazy var downloadButton: TransitionButton = {
        let button = TransitionButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 26, weight: .bold, scale: .default)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.down", withConfiguration: config)?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downloadButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.spinnerColor = .white
        return button
    }()
```