# How to add an image in the middle of UIButton title text?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to reach the following design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5kN3.png

How's it possible to set an image/icon in the middle of the button text?

Comment: May I suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697032/how-to-center-an-image-inside-an-uibutton-without-stretching-in-both-direction-i

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an image inside an UIButton without stretching in both direction in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697032/how-to-center-an-image-inside-an-uibutton-without-stretching-in-both-direction-i)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an attributed string for that:

```
// create a NSMutableAttributedString with the text before the image
let beginning = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Beginning")

// create a NSTextAttachment with the image
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "image.png")

// create an NSMutableAttributedString with the image
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)

// add the image to the string
beginning.append(imageString)

// create an NSMutableAttributedString with the text after the image
let end = NSAttributedString(string: "End")
beginning.append()

// set the attributed text of the label
label.attributedText = beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background image and set your labels right and left. Or you can create a new xib view, and extend UIButton as you wish and use it

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible options here:

1. Use an attributed string with image attachment
2. Use UIView with 2 labels and image inside with adding a tap gesture recognizer on it.